# Bump is invisible in 3d view or EEVEE render but visible in preview of material

Tags: texturing

I use EEVEE and bump is invisible in 3d view or render but visible in preview of material.

I am trying to make some cool bump muscle textures from a lesson but my bump doesn't look good.

In the preview of material it's looking cool but not in render.

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? (upload and share the URL it will generate) https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/c891a3087ba240b69855a636cc398101

Comment: it's not visible in Material Preview either, because the Distance value of the Normal Map is too low imho

Comment: Hello :). @moonboots is right. The sphere is 4.5 meters high, and bump height is set to just 10 milimeters

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not visible in *Material Preview* either, because the *Distance* value of the *Normal Map* is too low